# Getting Error in Web Demo during Integration

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, velo

I am getting the error 'Sorry, it seemed like there was an error during request.' [Dialogflow Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Xm3.jpg)

I tested the chatbot but I am getting the error. Should I make any changes in settings? Don't know what should I do. Actually I want to integrate dialogflow chatbot with my Wix website. Could someone help me with steps involved to integrate dialogflow with Wix?

Comment: Can you try navigating to `API & Services -> API Library -> Dialogflow API - STAGING` and make sure that it's enabled , if it is already enabled then disable it and enable it again. Let me know if this helps you or not.

Comment: Hi how do I navigate to API & Services in the dialogflow console? I couldn't understand what you are telling me to do! Could you explain please and tell me steps to follow?

Comment: Should I go to Google cloud and enable the Dialogflow API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the above issue you can try the below steps:

1. This issue commonly happens when the API is in  disabled state, you need to  enable it correctly.
   Navigating to API & Services -> API Library -> Dialogflow API - STAGING and make sure that it's enabled,if it is already enabled then disable it and enable it [again](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/setup#api). If this does not solve the issue then follow step2.
2. You may need to make sure the Dialogflow [service accoun](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/access-control#auto-service-accounts)t exists in the IAM page and has the necessary [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/access-control#roles)(Dialogflow API Admin & Dialogflow Console Agent Editor & Dialogflow Service Agent)
3. If you are using the Dialogflow API, you need to set up authentication. For more details you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/setup#auth).
4. Report the issue via [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=501190) if none of the above steps solves your issue.

Comment: The first step worked. I have enabled the Dialogflow API in Google Cloud. I don't have any of reputation points to upvote your answer. If you upvote my question then I will get 10 reputation points. Thanks for the detailed answer. By the way, will I be charged for using the Dialogflow API?

Comment: Hi @SakthivelT glad to know your issue is resolved.If my answer helped you please accept it.

Comment: I couldn't check the cost of using the API. Should I enable the credentials as well. Will it cost me something for using the API?

Comment: We cannot use dialogflow without enabling Dialogflow API.You will be charged for using dialogflow but it depends upon edition. For more details you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/pricing#es-agent)

Comment: How could I know how much I am charged. Could you help me with the steps please?

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment, you are charged based on your [edition](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/pricing#es-agent)(Dialogflow Trial Edition is available at no charge, there are limits on the amount of requests that you can make.).To know more about web demo integration you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/integration).

Comment: Hi I have added a Dialogflow messenger to my website sakthi.blog. I don't know whether I am using a free edition or a paid edition! could you please help me figure out which edition I am using? Hopefully mine is free but I am not sure! I am new to Google cloud, APIs, chat bots. Please help

Comment: Hi I just checked the cost under my API and I read something like, 'You have not incurred any cost. To enable account that would incur cost link it.' I think my Dialogflow is not yet charged. I don't have clarity about whether it will be charged or it will be free. I am not using the trail edition. I am using ES. If you find time please help me know if my account will incur cost or it will remain free.

Comment: Dialogflow ES agent has two editions Dialogflow Trial Edition and Dialogflow Essentials Edition(pay-as-you-go edition).Since you are new to Dialogflow most probably you are using the Trial Edition.Navigate to IAM & Admin page -> Quotas -> Search for Dialogflow in filter.Now below quotas you can see a description.Also based on my understanding you can see the upgrade option in the right side of the dialgflow es console if you are using trial edition else you can see Pay as you go. You can follow this [thread1](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/editions#es-agent) for more details.

Comment: Hope the above comment will help you.If still you have any confusion regarding  dialogflow edition, I suggest you create a new stack question.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. I forgot to tell you that I can see which edition of Dialogflow I am using in the console itself. I can see in the left side of the console that I am using Free Trial edition. Also there is an option to upgrade. Thanks for your answer.